# Does kern.hz still have any relevance in FreeBSD if "dynamic tick mode" is enabled?

Tags: virtualization, freebsd, kvm-virtualization

I'm running a FreeBSD 9.0 setup as a virtual machine in a [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) setup. In previous versions of FreeBSD it was common to force the `kern.hz` setting to a lower value so that the virtual machine does not keep the host busy because it's handling timer interrupts without having any work to do - the [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-guest.html) explains:

> The most important step is to reduce the kern.hz tunable to reduce the CPU utilization of FreeBSD under the Parallels environment. This is accomplished by adding the following line to
>
> /boot/loader.conf:
>   kern.hz=100
>
> Without this setting, an idle FreeBSD Parallels guest OS will use roughly 15% of the CPU of a single processor iMac®. After this change the usage will be closer to a mere 5%.

However, in FreeBSD 9, the "dynamic tick mode" (aka "tickless mode") is the default, controlled by the `kern.eventtimer.periodic` setting which defaults to `0` (read: tickless mode).

This makes me wonder - does the tip of lowering `kern.hz` still have any relevance for making FreeBSD 9 play nicely in a virtual machine setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While theoretically it should not be needed, according to this [Post on FreeBSD-Stable mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2012-March/066781.html) there seem to be problems using tickless VMs over longer periods of time on on VMware ESX 5.0 - which may or may not happen on KVM.

Comment: If you want to be 100% safe (or as close to it as you can with a relatively new OS), set FreeBSD 9 to use the standard "ticking" kernel (`kern.eventtimer.periodic = 1`) and set `kern.hz` as you would under previous versions.  With a tickless kernel `kern.hz` should have no effect.